# javascript tomorrow's date and 00:00 time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

So I'm trying to get add 1 day to today's date (tomorrow), but instead of having it it exactly 24 hours from when the query is run, I want it to be basically tomorrow morning 00:00..
eg if it's currently `Tue Jun 23 2020 13:01:57 GMT+0200` when I run `new Date()`, I need to get `Wed Jun 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200` to post to server (using axios).

Here's what I've tried, but it returns todays date at midnight.

```
  const today = new Date();
  const tomorrow = new Date(today);
  tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1);


  let payload =  {

    available_from: tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0),

}

axios.post(url, payload)......
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `setHours()` ***before*** `setDate()`

Comment: Using something like moment will make your life much easier with things like that.

Comment: @DimitriosMatanis : loading another library each and every time you need to solve some tiny issue can make your life whole lot harder at the end of the day when you need to maintain compatibility.

Comment: [*setHours*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) returns the adjusted time value of the date, so `available_from: tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0)` sets the value of *avaliable_from* to a number like 1592944099228. Set the time before assigning the date to *avaliable_from*.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Date.setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) to set the time on today's date to `24:00:00.000` i.e. tomorrow morning at midnight.

```js
const tomorrow = new Date();
console.log(tomorrow.toString());
tomorrow.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(tomorrow.toString());
```